# Unable to meet cordova requirements

Tags: android, cordova

After installing Cordova I get the following:

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Please install Android target / API level: "android-28".
Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat"
You will require:

1. "SDK Platform" for API level android-28
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
   Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-6.5.1\bin\gradle
   Some of requirements check failed*

However in SDK Manager form Android studio Android 10.0+ is installed and also SDK tools are in place.
All ENV variables seems all right, too.
What can I try?
Could be that Android 10 is not supported, as somebody suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, I had overlooked the fact that android studio installs by default an API level of 30 (corresponding to android 10+).
I just added in sdkmanager android 9 (api level 28 as requested by the prompt)